# No Turn-by-Turn Directions on Google Navigation

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-navigation

Google Maps gets fairly frequent updates (although I don't use it all that much). But, I have recently had to use it for some travel. I noticed that, where Google Maps used to give directions in this fashion...

"Turn left onto Main Street in 0.2 miles."

...ever since I did an update (no clue which update it was - as I said, I don't use directions THAT frequently) now all it says is...

"Left"

Needless to say, this makes it rather painful to use for direction purposes. What do I need to do to fix this? I Googled around, but didn't find anything. Would appreciate suggestions.

Comment: Is this Google Maps or Google Navigation?

Comment: @LieRyan - Technically, I suppose it is Google Navigation. (I'm browsing to the street address through Google Maps.)

Comment: This is a known issue with some versions of ICS: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/maps/FDKwbM5zMuU/TthydW9YLhoJ

Comment: @Zooks64 - Oog. That's a bummer. Well, I just got 4.0.4 (the OTA pushes have begun). Next time I'm out driving, I'll test it out to see if the problem has resolved itself.

Comment: @JasCav I just installed the 4.0.4 update yesterday but haven't had any reason to try out the turn by turn directions since then. I sure hope that it is resolved - I got spoiled with the street names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the issue appeared to be specifically with a Google Maps update. I have received two updates over Google Play since then and the problem appears to have resolved.